# showing the creators name of the post in react using post list

Tags: reactjs, api, ecmascript-6, redux, es6-promise

I'm creating a list of posts with the creators' name in react and

> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com users and posts API's

my actions file

```
 export const fetchuser = (id) => async dispatch => {
        const response = await instance.get(`./users/${id}`)
        dispatch({
            type : "GET_USERS",
            payload :response.data
        })
    }
```

my component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {fetchuser} from '../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Postuser extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchuser(this.props.userid)
    }
    render() {
        const user = this.props.users.find((user) => user.id === this.props.userId);
        if(!user){
            return null
        }
       return <div>{user.name}</div>
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
       users:state.users 
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{fetchuser})(Postuser)
```

reducer

```
export default function userreducer(state=[], action) {
       switch(action.type){
        case"GET_USERS" :
        return [...state, action.payload]
        default : return state
       }
}
```

parent component where I use this component

```
 <Postuser userId={post.userId} />
```

---

I'm getting this error message please check

> ET https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/undefined 404
>   2createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with
>   status code 404
>       at createError (createError.js:17)
>       at settle (settle.js:19)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you are doing something wrong, you are passing userId as

```
 <Postuser userId={post.userId} />
```

but not accessing it rightly do it as this

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchuser(this.props.userId) // I capital
}
```

Hope it helps